# Is there a workaround for using Wagtail Image tags in views.py

Tags: django, wagtail

I've the following problem: 
In my models.py I'm using a Wagtail Image  like this:

```
class ArtWork(models.Model):
    image = models.ForeignKey(
            'wagtailimages.Image',
            on_delete=models.CASCADE,
            related_name='+'
        )
    ...
    ...
    ...
```

I know i can use the Image in my templates now like this:

```
{% image artwork.image height-100 %}
```

But for my current project I need to use the Image tag in my views.py because I'd like to generate a Pdf with it.

by simple using `artwork.image` just the Title of the Image returns but I'd need something like:

```
<img alt="SomeName" src="/media/images/SomeName_155x200.max-1200x1200_22b3pND.height-100.jpg" width="77" height="100">
```

Also `artwork.image.url` gives no result.
How can I use Wagtail Images outside my templates?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you need to get an URL of rendition (thumbnail), you can do the following:

```
artwork_page_object.image.get_rendition('height-100').url
```

or to access rendition file:

```
artwork_page_object.image.get_rendition('height-100').file
```

Instead of `height-100` you can use any valid resizing method for the `image` template tag (see [the documentation for the `image`](http://docs.wagtail.io/en/v1.9/topics/images.html#using-images-in-templates) tag)

If you want to access original image you can do it like:

```
artwork_page_object.image.file
```

Useful docs:

- Wagtail: [More control over page rendering](http://docs.wagtail.io/en/v1.9/topics/pages.html#more-control-over-page-rendering)
- Wagtail: [Generating renditions in Python](http://docs.wagtail.io/en/latest/advanced_topics/images/renditions.html) (Thanks, @shacker)
- Django: [ImageField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ImageField) and [FileField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/fields/#filefield)

Comment: The get_rendition() method was undocumented until a week ago - I just contributed the new official documentation on that: http://docs.wagtail.io/en/latest/advanced_topics/images/renditions.html

Comment: Thanks, @shacker. I've added your link to the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Template tags are just functions you can find the code [on github](https://github.com/wagtail/wagtail/blob/master/wagtail/wagtailimages/templatetags/wagtailimages_tags.py). The image tag relies on the models [`Filter`](https://github.com/wagtail/wagtail/blob/master/wagtail/wagtailimages/models.py#L338) and [`Rendition`](https://github.com/wagtail/wagtail/blob/master/wagtail/wagtailimages/models.py#L440).

I would recommend to read that code to understand how it works and afterwards use it in your view.

Answer (score 0):

As noted by user Shacker here are the docs: https://docs.wagtail.org/en/stable/advanced_topics/images/renditions.html#image-renditions

Example:

```
# in your models
from wagtail.core.models import Page

class MyCustomPageModel(Page):
    photo = models.ForeignKey(
    'wagtailimages.Image',
    ...

# in your view
from myapp.models import MyCustomPageModel
  
p = MyCustomPageModel.objects.all()[0]
r = p.photo.get_rendition('fill-300x150')
print(r.url)
```